# JS function to validate input name not working correctly

Tags: javascript, validation

The objective of this code is to check the name the user inputs. If the value contains something other than `-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` the function will throw an error.

I am unable to get this to work, and I'm not allowed to use Regular expressions. I've also tried `String1.indexOf(usr.substr(i,1)) > -1)` but that doesn't seem to work neither.

```
function nameValidation(username) {
    var usr = document.getElementById("username").value;
    usr = usr.trim();
    var alpha = "-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var ok = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < usr.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(usr[i])) {
            ok = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            ok = 1;
            document.getElementById("fnerror").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "lightgrey";
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (ok == 0) {
        document.getElementById("fnerror").innerHTML = "X Enter Upper and lower case      letters, hypen, apostrohe only please";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just match against `/[^azAZ-']/`?

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm not allowed to use regEx. Ill add to the post now

Comment: You're... not allowed to use regex?

Comment: Homework question, I assume.

Comment: Well, if you could use Regex, this would be a one-liner.  Something like `/[^A-z-']/`

Comment: exactly! I wish I was able to use regex

Comment: Your function currently doesn't use `alpha` at all? Also, you surely don't want to `return true;` immediately after you've found the first valid character.

Comment: alpha was there perviously when I was using substr, I left it there accidentally while trying different ways of validation. return ture; thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
function isValidUsername(username) {
  var alpha = "-'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  username = username.toUpperCase();
  for (var i = 0, l = username.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (alpha.indexOf(username[i]) === -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Cheaper to upper-case the string and therefore have a shorter set of characters to test against (though probably marginal at best because there's a cost to even native-uppercasing..)

Comment: Darn, beat me to it.  Although you can declare `alpha` outside of the function, that way you're not unnecessarily declaring it each call (since it will always be the same, not dynamic to the function).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a more "functional way", by using `every` method, which allow us to break a loop instead of `foreach`.

> The every method executes the provided callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a falsy value (a value that becomes false when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns false. Otherwise, if callback returned a true value for all elements, every will return true. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.
>
> [Array.proototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

So :

```
function check(){

  //Get value input and transform it into array
  var value = document.querySelector('#username').value.split('');

  var alpha = "-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  //If there is an error, stop the loop and return result
  return value.every(function(elm){

    //check if elm is an alpha string
    return alpha.indexOf(elm) > -1;
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (to understand at least) solution (that doesn't use regex), would be to loop through your string character by character and check `.indexOf` against your list of allowed characters, something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (alpha.indexOf(input[i])==-1) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I read the question wrong and thought you wanted to return true if there's a letter. It will now make sure that each character is within the ASCII values of `A` and `z`.

```js
text = "ABCDEFzzxasd1";
valid = true;

for( i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) {
    if ( text.charCodeAt(i) < 65 || text.charCodeAt(i) > 122 ) {
        alert("Woah, that's not a letter!");
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped me as well as the other comments!

Answer (score 0):

Begin with

```
var alpha = "-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');

function duplicates( element, index, array ){
  return array.indexOf(element) == index;
}

function isNameFormatCorrect( userName ){
  return ( alpha.concat(username.split(''))
    .filter( duplicates ).length === alpha.length );
}
```

Then

```
var username = "YourUserNameHere-"
isNameFormatCorrect( username ); => true;

var username = "YourUserNameHere-**"
isNameFormatCorrect( username ); => false;
```